# How to take a value from one table, split it on space, and place each word in a new row, MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a MySql database, containing business names. I want a key-value type of search, containing both parts of the name, city e.g.

So, if the company name is named Foo Bar, i need to split it into "Foo" and "Bar", and insert into a new table. I have used the following query to add the city, but then I did not need to split the string:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO search_key (`id`,`key`) SELECT `id`,`city` FROM company WHERE `city`<>''
```

How can I split the name if it contains more than one word, an place it as separate rows into the search_key table?

Comment: Here is a list of options http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
insert into search_key(`id`,`key`) (
 select `id`, replace(substring(substring_index(`city`, ' ', 1), length(substring_index(`city`, ' ', 1 - 1)) + 1), ' ', '') as `city`
        from company
```